# Is there any way to calculate the % by which results differ in relation to each other based just on input and output data?

Tags: computer-science, percentages, ratio

I have a black box algorithm that calculates a volume of a liquid that passed through a sensor. I also have a way to "re calibrate" the algorithm to produce a new out come.

e.g. I poured some fluid, weighted it, and it's `355 grams`.
The algorithm claims that's `349 ml`.

I re-calibrate it, pour some fluid again, and wight it at `355 grams`. The algorithm claims that's `354 ml`.

I know that `349g / 354g = 0.98587570621`.
When I multiply `354g * 0.98587570621 = 348.999999998ml`
Therefore I can claim that the old calibration was `1.412429379%` under counting compared to the new one.

How can I do this when I don't have exact weights and volumes?

Let's say calibration 1 was `378g` which produced `372ml`.
And calibration 2 is `358g` which produced `352ml`.

Is there any way to calculate the % by which these volumes are inaccurate in relation to each other based on the weights?

Comment: @AdrianKeister That just tells me the difference between volumes but the weight impacts the volume.

Comment: You asked to calculate the % difference between the volumes, and what I typed up is how to do it. If you don't have the volumes, then you need to make that clear in your question. If you are calculating volumes based on something else, then please post your equation.

Comment: @AdrianKeister There, I re-worded it. Please read the whole thing.